# Adding AVTimedMetadataGroup to AVMutableComposition to create chapter marks in (temporary) video

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3, avfoundation

I'm trying to add chapters to an `AVMutableComposition`. The video is created as expected and sent to the `AVPlayer`. How ever I would like to include chapter marks (to use the Chapter marker option in `AVplayer`).

I have tried the following to create the timed metadata... but than what to do??

When trying to add metadata to the `AVMutableComposition` all items for metadata are get only.

```
let someAsset:AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url:URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/temp.mov"))
let mutableComposition:AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
let start: Int64 = 0
let duration: Int64 = 500
let timeRange:CMTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(start), timescale: 1), end: CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(duration), timescale: 1));
var timedMetadataItems: [AVTimedMetadataGroup] = []

do {
    try mutableComposition.insertTimeRange(timeRange, of: someAsset, at: mutableComposition.duration)


    let metadata = AVMutableMetadataItem()
    metadata.key = AVMetadataQuickTimeUserDataKeyChapter as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol
    metadata.value = "Test" as NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol

    let timedMetadata = AVTimedMetadataGroup(items: [metadata], timeRange: timeRange)
    timedMetadataItems.append(timedMetadata)

} catch let error as NSError {
    Swift.print(error.localizedDescription)
}

return AVPlayerItem(asset: mutableComposition)
```

If doing this without writing to disk is really impossible (what feels strange) any help with saving the video with the chapters would be great as well. As I can only save normal meta data.

With `AVAssetExportSession` it is possible to set the metadata and write the new composition to a file, but it’s not possible to write a `AVTimedMetadataGroup`?

```
let export = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mutableComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem possible to add `AVTimedMetadataGroup` directly to an AVComposition, however any timed metadata present in the videos you are combining will pass through.

I have verified that this works (although I haven't tried chapter markers specifically) for compositions exported with `AVAssetExportSession` and for playback with `AVPlayerItemMetadataOutputPushDelegate`

This is covered briefly in the [WWDC 2014 Session 505 "Harnessing Metadata in Audiovisual Media"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/505/) video at 35:50

Comment: You're link is bad.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to add timed metadata to a composition. You will just have to work with the metadata in memory until you write it to disk.

The only way to write timed metadata to a file is to use an `AVAssetWriter`.
To do this you need to set up the asset writer as usual, but then add a metadata track:

```
let formatDesc = aMetadataGroup.copyFormatDescription()
let metadataInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .metadata, outputSettings: nil, sourceFormatHint: formatDesc)
metadataInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = false
writer?.add(metadataInput)
```

Then you set up a metadataAdaptor and use that to append the metadata groups whenever the metadataInput is ready.

```
let metadataAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputMetadataAdaptor(assetWriterInput: metadataInput)
metadataInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: metadataQueue, using: {
    metadataAdaptor.append(metadataGroup)
})
```

You can retrieve the metadata from this file again by using a `AVAssetReaderOutputMetadataAdaptor` with the metadata track.